# Title do not appear on android action bar

Tags: android

I am trying to style my actionbar with background color. I have also given label in the android manifest file which shows up in the action bar. But when i  try to change background color using Style.xml , it changes the background color but do not show label.
Below is the Style xml

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->

</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>  
 </style>


<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@color/actionbarcolor</item>
</style>
```

could you please let me know , what change  i should make so that it shows label name also after applying background color.

I have applied theme "AppTheme" at application level in manifest file .

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this

```
<style>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/AwesomeTabTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AwesomeTabTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text_color</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks nayoso. I tried to add above lines but it did not work.I added "android:actionBarTabTextStyle" under <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">.

Comment: What is the color of your actionbar?

Comment: I have used parent as <style name="AwesomeTabTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText" since "@android:style/Widget.ActionBar.TabText" is not applicable for api below 13. i have kept minimum api level as 11.